Display the second text after finishing printing the first text
I want the first text to be printed first, and then after finishing printing the first text; The second text will start to be printed.
In the code I wrote, the first text is printed well, but the second text is not printed for me.
Also, I tried hard to apply a sign (|) while printing each word to convey the feeling of typing to the user, but I couldn't make it work. Please guide me in this matter as well.
My codes:


const text1 = "Your first sentence here"; // Enter your first sentence here
const text2 = "Your second sentence here"; // Enter your second sentence here

let i = 0;
let isFinished = false;

function typeSentence(text, element) {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (i === text.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            isFinished = true;

            if (element === $('#loading-text')) {
                // Check if the first sentence is finished
                if (isFinished) {
                    // Start typing the second sentence after finishing the first sentence
                    i = 0;
                    typeSentence(text2, $('#loading-text2'));
                }
            }
        } else {
            element.text(element.text() + text[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
}

typeSentence(text1, $('#loading-text'));
 #loading-text, #loading-text2 {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-text"></div>
<div id="loading-text2"></div>




you can simplify your code and juste call typeSentence for second text if it have not been already call


const text1 = "Your first sentence here"; // Enter your first sentence here
const text2 = "Your second sentence here"; // Enter your second sentence here

let i = 0;
let isFinished = false;

function typeSentence(text, element) {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (i === text.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            if ($('#loading-text2').text() !== text2) {
               i = 0;
               typeSentence(text2, $('#loading-text2'));
            }
        } else {
            element.text(element.text() + text[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
}

typeSentence(text1, $('#loading-text'));
#loading-text, #loading-text2 {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-text"></div>
<div id="loading-text2"></div>




Here is a simpler and somewhat DRYer version using interval


const texts = ["Your first sentence here", "Your second sentence here"];
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=loading-text]');
let tId, currentTextIdx = 0, currentIndex = 0;

const typeSentence = () => {
  if (currentIndex < texts[currentTextIdx].length) {
    elements[currentTextIdx].textContent += texts[currentTextIdx][currentIndex];
    currentIndex++;
  } else if (currentTextIdx < texts.length - 1) {
    currentTextIdx++;
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  else clearInterval(tId); // stop
};
tId = setInterval(typeSentence, 100);  
div[id^=loading-text] {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
<div id="loading-text1"></div>
<div id="loading-text2"></div>



